# Proper Way To Retrieve Values in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am quite new to Firebase and was reading the docs and tried several solutions. How can I retrieve the data "friendID" in the following structure. I only need to retrieve this data once every time this view is loaded.

[image]

And here is my latest attempt.

```
let profileDB = Database.database().reference().child("Profiles")
profileDB.child(userID!).child("friends").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
(snapshot) in

    let dbValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    if let friend = dbValue?["friendID"] {
        print(friend)
    }
})
```

**UPDATE**:

If I do this:

```
let dbValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
print(dbValue)
```

OR:

```
let dbValue = snapshot.value
print(dbValue)
```

Then I get this but not sure how to access the `friendID` key.

```
Optional({
"-LWS8PMygzX2Lk-hOGvT" =     {
    friendID = qvhN5UMnbOWvfhhN4RAHtwjLuwG2;
};
"-LWS8PNFdUGMI1gHO8TF" =     {
    friendID = w3f7yLMdArUrnKLWR1nyE7ko1ds1;
};
})
```

If I change to this then it works. But isn't the first observe method above better for 1 time retrievals?

```
profileDB.child(userID!).child("friends").observe(.childAdded) {
(snapshot) in

    let dbValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

    if let friend = dbValue["friendID"] {
        print(friend)
    }
}
```

My last question would be once I grab this friend ID how can I load up their info? Would I call the db again inside of this observer? This seems to work:

```
let profileDB = Database.database().reference().child("Profiles")

profileDB.child(userID!).child("friends").observe(.childAdded) {
(snapshot) in

    let dbValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

    if let friendID = dbValue["friendID"] {
    print(friendID)

    let friendProfileDB = Database.database().reference().child("Profiles")
    friendProfileDB.child(friendID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
    (snapshot) in

        let friendDBValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        if let name = friendDBValue?["name"] {
            print(name)
        }
    })
}
```

Any help would be awesome and thanks in advance!

Comment: In regards to your second question, it really depends on what the function you are writing for this is trying to achieve. Think, "what is my input? And what is my output?". If it is a function that given a user will grab all of the user's friends, then I would do it in the same method.

Also, your variable names could be a bit misleading, this is more of an opinion than a suggestion. But `profileDB` is misleading in that it is not actually a Database but rather a `Collection` contained in the database

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was thinking the same about the naming convention and was planning on updating that end of it. Thanks for confirming that the last method I wrote will work fine for just retrieving the friends info with no updates planned for this view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should work. You seem to have a solid understanding of the firebase key/value tree node structure. If the database reference is correct, you should be able to examine each child by its key to eventually arrive at your value.

I would verify each of your keys are correct.

Comment: Thank you! I checked and made sure it was. Please see updated post above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `friends` is an Array, so checking for friendID directly would not work. Perhaps try accessing snapshot.value as an NSArray, then loop through the items in `snapshot.value` and check if any of those have a friendID that matches.

Comment: Thanks! Can you show me an example? Also see updated section of my question above.

Answer (score 0):

If the aim of friends node is to store friend ids, you’d rather store each friend id as a key right under the friends node.
The structure would be like this :

```
 friends
    + qvhN5UMnbOWvfhhN4RAHtwjLuwG2: 0
    + w3f7yLMdArUrnKLWR1nyE7ko1ds1: 0
    + otherFrienID: 0
```

Now you can easily loop through your dictionary like below (not tested):

```
let profileDB = Database.database().reference().child("Profiles")
profileDB.child(userID!).child("friends").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
 (snapshot) in    

  let dbValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  var friendsIds = [String]()

  for (key, value) in dbValue {
   friendsIds.append(key)
  //Here you can query firebase for the name corresponding to the friendId
  }
})
```

Then you can request Firebase to fetch the name corresponding to every `friendsIds`.

But better than that, you could have saved your `friendsIds` coupled with their corresponding names so that you don't have to make additional queries.
In this case, the original structure would look like this:

```
 friends
    + qvhN5UMnbOWvfhhN4RAHtwjLuwG2: "John Doe"
    + w3f7yLMdArUrnKLWR1nyE7ko1ds1: "Steve Jobs"
    + otherFrienID: "Peter Pan"
```

Data redundancy in order to easierly access data is not a crime in Firebase, this is called denormalization and is part of best practices.

Then, here is how you would fetch your friends name in a single query:

```
let profileDB = Database.database().reference().child("Profiles")
profileDB.child(userID!).child("friends").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
 (snapshot) in    

  let dbValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  var friendsNames = [String]()

  for (key, value) in dbValue {
   friendsNames.append(value)
  //No additional query here
  }
})
```